# How to do Geofence monitoring/analytics using KSQLDB?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, confluent-platform

I am trying to do geofence monitoring/analytics using KSQLDB. I want to get a message whenever a vehicle ENTERS/LEAVES a geofence. Taking inspiration from the [https://github.com/gschmutz/various-demos/tree/master/kafka-geofencing] I have created a UDF named as GEOFENCE, below is the code for the same.

Below is my query to perform join on geofence stream and live vehicle position stream

```
CREATE stream join_live_pos_geofence_status_1 AS SELECT lp1.vehicleid, 
          lp1.lat, 
          lp1.lon, 
          s1p.geofencecoordinates, 
          Geofence(lp1.lat, lp1.lon, 'POLYGON(('+s1p.geofencecoordinates+'))') AS geofence_status 
FROM      live_position_1 LP1 
LEFT JOIN stream_1_processed S1P within 72 hours 
ON        kmdlp1.clusterid = kmds1p.clusterid emit changes;
```

I am taking into account all the geofences created in last 3 days.

I have created another query to use the geofence status from previous query to calculate whether the vehicle is ENTERING/LEAVING geofence.

```
CREATE stream join_geofence_monitoring_1 AS SELECT *, 
       Geofence(jlpgs1.lat, jlpgs1.lon, 'POLYGON(('+jlpgs1.geofencecoordinates+'))', jlpgs1.geofence_status) geofence_monitoring_status
FROM   join_live_pos_geofence_status_1 JLPGS1 emit changes;
```

The above query give me the output as 'INSIDE', 'INSIDE' for geofence_status and geofence_monitoring_status columns, respectively or the output is 'OUTSIDE', 'OUTSIDE' for geofence_status and geofence_monitoring_status columns, respectively. I know I am not taking into account the time aspect, like these 2 queries should never be executed at same time say 't0' but I am not able to think the correct way of doing this.

```
public class Geofence 
{
    private static final String OUTSIDE = "OUTSIDE";
    private static final String INSIDE = "INSIDE";
    private static GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
    private static WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader(geometryFactory);

    @Udf(description = "Returns whether a coordinate lies within a polygon or not")
    public static String geofence(final double latitude, final double longitude, String geometryWKT) {
        boolean status = false;
        String result = "";
        Polygon polygon = null;
        try {
            polygon = (Polygon) wktReader.read(geometryWKT);

            // However, an important point to note is that the longitude is the X value 
            // and the latitude the Y value. So we say "lat/long", 
            // but JTS will expect it in the order "long/lat". 
            Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(longitude, latitude);
            Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(coord);

            status = point.within(polygon);
            if(status)
            {
                result = INSIDE;
            }
            else
            {
                result = OUTSIDE;
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Udf(description = "Returns whether a coordinate moved in or out of a polygon")
    public static String geofence(final double latitude, final double longitude, String geometryWKT, final String statusBefore) {

        String status = geofence(latitude, longitude, geometryWKT);
        if (statusBefore.equals("INSIDE") && status.equals("OUTSIDE")) {
            //status = "LEAVING";
            return "LEAVING";
        } else if (statusBefore.equals("OUTSIDE") && status.equals("INSIDE")) {
            //status = "ENTERING";
            return "ENTERING";
        }
        return status;
    }

}
```

My question is how can I calculate correctly that a vehicle is ENTERING/LEAVING a geofence? Is it even possible to do with KSQLDB?

Comment: @AndrewCoates  The logic for ENTERING or LEAVING should be written in the overrided merge method of the custom UDAF or in the map method ? I have written the UDAF but it return the same value that is passed to it. Have a look pastebin.com/vW44NYFb I am using confluent 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be correct to say that the join_live_pos_geofence_status_1  stream can have rows that go from INSIDE -> OUTSIDE and then from OUTSIDE -> INSIDE for some key value?

And what you're wanting to do is to output `LEAVING` and `ENTERING` events for these transitions?

You can likely do what you want using a custom UDAF.  Custom UDAFs take and input and calculate an output, via some intermediate state.  For example, an AVG udaf would take some numbers as input, its intermediate state would be the number of inputs and the sum of inputs, and the output would be count/sum.

In your case, the input would be the current state, e.g. either `INSIDE` or `OUTSIDE`.  The UDAF would need to store the last two states in its intermediate state, and then the output state can be calculated from this. E.g.

```
Input   Intermediate    Output
INSIDE  INSIDE          <only single in intermediate - your choice what you output>
INSIDE  INSIDE,INSIDE   no-change
OUTSIDE INSIDE,OUTSIDE  LEAVING
OUTSIDE OUTSIDE,OUTSIDE no-change
INSIDE  OUTSIDE,INSIDE  ENTERING
```

You'll need to decide what to output when there is only a single entry in the intermediate state, i.e. the first time a key is seen.

You can then filter the output to remove any rows that have `no-change`.

You may also need to set `cache.max.bytes.buffering` to zero to stop any results being conflated.

**UPDATE**: suggested code.

Not tested, but something like the following code may do what you want:

```
@UdafDescription(name = "my_geofence", description = "Computes the geofence status.")
public final class GoeFenceUdaf {

  private static final String STATUS_1 = "STATUS_1";
  private static final String STATUS_2 = "STATUS_2";

  @UdafFactory(description = "Computes the geofence status.",
      aggregateSchema = "STRUCT<" + STATUS_1 + " STRING, " + STATUS_2 + " STRING>")
  public static Udaf<String, Struct, String> calcGeoFenceStatus() {

    final Schema STRUCT_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.struct().optional()
        .field(STATUS_1, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
        .field(STATUS_2, Schema.OPTIONAL_STRING_SCHEMA)
        .build();

    return new Udaf<String, Struct, String>() {

      @Override
      public Struct initialize() {
        return new Struct(STRUCT_SCHEMA);
      }

      @Override
      public Struct aggregate(
          final String newValue,
          final Struct aggregate
      ) {
        if (newValue == null) {
          return aggregate;
        }

        if (aggregate.getString(STATUS_1) == null) {
          // First status for this key:
          return aggregate
              .put(STATUS_1, newValue);
        }

        final String lastStatus = aggregate.getString(STATUS_2);
        if (lastStatus == null) {
          // Second status for this key:
          return aggregate
              .put(STATUS_2, newValue);
        }

        // Third and subsequent status for this key:
        return aggregate
            .put(STATUS_1, lastStatus)
            .put(STATUS_2, newValue);
      }

      @Override
      public String map(final Struct aggregate) {
        final String previousStatus = aggregate.getString(STATUS_1);
        final String currentStatus = aggregate.getString(STATUS_2);
        if (currentStatus == null) {
          // Only have single status, i.e. first status for this key
          // What to do?  Probably want to do:
          return previousStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("OUTSIDE")
              ? "LEAVING"
              : "ENTERING";
        }

        // Two statuses ...
        if (currentStatus.equals(previousStatus)) {
          return "NO CHANGE";
        }

        return previousStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("OUTSIDE")
            ? "ENTERING"
            : "LEAVING";
      }

      @Override
      public Struct merge(final Struct agg1, final Struct agg2) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Function does not support session windows");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: The logic for ENTERING or LEAVING should be written in the overrided merge method of the custom UDAF or  in the map method ? I have written the UDAF but it return the same value that is passed to it. Have a look https://pastebin.com/vW44NYFb I am using confluent 5.4.

Comment: `merge` is only called for session windows - which this solution won't work with: so I'd throw an 'not supported' exception from merge.

Your code has a strange intermediate schema. No idea what the `COUNT` field is for. Let me update my answer with updated code.

Comment: I had used count as I had taken inspiration from AVG UDAF. So when count=0 then it means this is the first geofence status and I have to return the same geofence status as I had received. But I had almost zero idea on how to use the map, merge and aggregate methods. Thanks for making me understand this and the answer you provided works perfectly fine.